# Unable to get Prestashop Bitnami Stack 1.7 working on Windows

Tags: prestashop, bitnami, prestashop-1.7

I am fairly new to Bitnami and Prestashop and having issues getting it running

- installed Oracle Virtual Box
- Imported the Prestashop 1.7 bitnami file as a new VM only changing the RAM to 2GB ( I did this part a few times )

I made no changes to the network - but I noticed that when I logged in the VM didn't have access to the internet ( does it need to? )

So - everything seemed ok, but when I went to the IP address suggested on the screen of the VM - I got a 500 error. So I put prestashop in dev mode ( edited the config file ) then I got the following error:

```
// No shop found ... too bad, let's redirect to default shop
$default_shop = new Shop(Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_DEFAULT'));

// Hmm there is something really bad in your Prestashop !
if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($default_shop)) {
throw new PrestaShopException('Shop not found');
}
$params = $_GET;
unset($params['id_shop']);
$url = $default_shop->domain;
```

With the line: throw new PrestaShopException('Shop not found');    in Red.

I am not sure why it doesn't just run or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this file classes/shop/Shop.php? maybe this link can help you if you didn't have the file https://www.prestatoolbox.com/content/33-shop-not-found-at-line-404-in-file-classes-shop-shop-php

Are you upgrade Prestashop or is it a fresh install?
If you upgrade the application check the theme is update right.

You can check the apache log (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log`) if are anything about this error.